# Upload two different file in one form

Tags: javascript, laravel

Having a hard time fixing my two upload file.My Problem is when i upload a photo in the first form file, the preview displays same photo both in the two form for file and ngo_logo and the same as when i upload photo in the second form file for ngo_logo, it displays the same photo both in the form.The first one is always overridden.Anyone could help me out here is much appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Proof of Accreditation<em>(Upload File)</em>:</label>
            {!! Form::file('file',['class'=>'form‐control','id'=>'file'  ]) !!}
          </div> 
         <div class="form-group">
              <img id="fil" src="#" name="file"  class="img-responsive well" alt="Image" />
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Organizational Logo:</label>
             {!! Form::file('ngo_logo',['class'=>'form‐control','id'=>'ngo_logo'  ]) !!}
           </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
          <img id="logo" src="#" name="ngo_logo"  class="img-responsive well" alt=" Your Image" />
             </div>
     </div>
```

/**Javascript**/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#fil').attr('src', e.target.result);
                //$('#logo').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#logo').attr('src', e.target.result);

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }



    }/**end of function readURL(input)**/
        $("#file").change(function(){
            readURL(this);       
        });
        $("#ngo_logo").change(function(){
            readURL(this);       
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read file twice, just need to target correct element and set `src`.

You can use DOM relationship to target the desired element and set the `SRC`. there are various methods to traverse DOM with current element context i.e. [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
function readURL(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(event.target)
            .closest('form-group') //Target parent form control div
            .next() //Target sibling of parent form control 
            .find('img') //Target Ima
            .attr('src', e.target.result); //Set image
        } 
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#file, #ngo_logo").change(readURL);
```

References

1. [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
3. [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

---

As an alternative, you can associate the element using `data-*` prefixed attributes.

```
{!! Form::file('file',['class'=>'form‐control','id'=>'file', data-target=>'#fil' ]) !!}
{!! Form::file('ngo_logo',['class'=>'form‐control','id'=>'ngo_logo', data-target=>'#logo' ]) !!}
```

and in the event handler read it using `$.fn.data()` or `Element.dataset` property.

```
function readURL(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(event.target).data('target').attr('src', e.target.result);
            //$(event.target.dataset.target).attr('src', e.target.result);
        } 
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i target this two   $('#fil').attr('src', e.target.result); and 
                        $('#logo').attr('src', e.target.result);

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::file('file',['class'=>'form‐control','id'=>'file'  ]) !!}
```

Replace `id=>file` with `id=>fil` because your image id is `fil`.

```
<img id="fil" src="#" name="file" class="img-responsive well" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: Sir, id=>file is for $("#file").change(function(){
            readURL(this);   and <img id="fil" is for $('#fil').attr('src', e.target.result);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.